# Detect triangles, ellipses and rectangles from an image

Tags: opencv, detection

I am trying to detect the regions of traffic signs. Using OpenCV, my approach is as follows:

The color image:

[image]

Using the [TanTriggs Preprocessing](https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/blob/master/misc/tan_triggs.cpp) get rid of the illumination variances:

[image]

Equalize histogram:

[image]

And binarize `(Cv2.Threshold(blobs, blobs, 127, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv)`:

[image]

Iterate each blob using [ConnectedComponents](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a) and [get the mean color value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603941/1266873) using the blob as mask. If it is a red color then it may be a red sign.

Then get contours of this blob using [FindContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours).

Simplify the contours using [ApproxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) and check the points of each contour:

- If 3 points then triangle shape is acceptable --> candidate for triangle sign
- If 4 points then shape is acceptable --> candidate
- If more than 4 points, BBox dimensions are acceptable and most of the points are on the ellipse fitted ([FitEllipse](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitellipse#fitellipse)) --> candidate

This approach works for the separated blobs in the binary image, like the circular 100km sign in my example. However if there is a connection to the outside objects, like the triangle left bottom part in the binary image, it fails.

[image]

Because, the mean value of this blob is far from red!

Using [Erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) helps in some cases, however makes it worse in many of the other images.

Using different threshold values for the binarization also works for some, but fails on many; like the erosion.

Using [HoughCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) is just very slow and I couldn't manage to get good results playing with the parameters.

I have tried using `matchShapes` but couldn't get good results.

Can anybody show me another way the achieve what I want (with a reasonable computational time)?

Any information, or code in any language is wellcome.

**Edit:**
Using [circularity measure](https://thinnkit.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/a-new-approach-in-shape-detection-using-area-analysis-traffic-sign-board-detection/) ([C=P^2/4πA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy))) or the approach I have described above, triangle and ellips shapes can be found when they are separated. However when the contour is like this for example:
[image]

I could not find a robust way to extract the triangle piece. If I could, I would check the mean color, and decide if its a red sign candidate.

Comment: Have you tried morphological opening (erosion + dilation) rather than just erosion? It could help with removing noisy connections while preserving originally solid connected components.

Comment: Yes I have tried different kernel types and sizes. Erosion-Dilation, Dilatio-Erosion etc. General success always diminished. Also tried some blurring (gaussian, pyrdown-up etc.) which also decreased the success.

Comment: Could it be so that machine learning is applicable to the task? If you possess some traffic sign learning base, you could train a Haar cascade or a neural network to do the sign detection for you.

Comment: If still approaching the problem from the image processing side, you could take a look at this article: [Real-time line detection through an improved Hough transform voting scheme by Fernandes and Oliveira](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Leandro_Fernandes3/publication/220604337_Real-time_line_detection_through_an_improved_Hough_transform_voting_scheme/links/0046351d1fc9f36b47000000.pdf). It presents a fast and robust Hough transofrm, but, unfortunately, I have not seen it implemented in OpenCV or anywhere.

Comment: I use HOG features trained SVM for the classification stage. However my SVM tries showed me that I should find the correct ROI where the traffic sign exists. In order to increase the sucess I need that. Or don't I?

Comment: Yes, the training samples quite preferably should contain just the desired target of detection (give or take some minor error for background or something). And the target should presented from different view angles. Unless I'm very wrong, this goes to any classifier and descriptive features choice.

Comment: My training samples are the cropped sings. I use the OpenCV SVM for classification (feed it with HOG features) and it is only successful if I could find the Rect of the sing and use it for prediction. Including BOW approach (which is unstable with EMGU and OpenCVSharp) classifiers cannot predict from an whole scene image; as far as I see. If there is a way of doing that; it would be very appreciated if you show me a way.

Comment: Sorry, I understood you other way round. It is a notable issue, but, I'm afraid, I can't really tell what is the problem from scratch. Though I can suggest illumination normalization (the abovementioned TanTriggs preprocessing) for both training and testing sets. Maybe that could ease the task for the classifier.

Comment: I use http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset#Downloads datasets for score calculation and achieved %87.81 F1Score using EqualizeHistogram for the 40x40 resized train and predicting images. (tested 64x64, success increased but slower) I ve tried TanTriggs instead of simple histogram equalization, suprisingly the success diminished. Unsuccessful images are the ones that I could not find the correct ROI for the signs. If I could find a solution for this question, it would make a difference, I hope, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have the kudos to comment, but can't you use the red colour?

```
import common
myshow = common.myshow

img = cv2.imread("ms0QB.png")
grey = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_mask = np.logical_or(hsv[:,:,0]>160,hsv[:,:,0]<10 )
grey[mask] = 255
cv2.imshow("160<hue<182",grey)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thats a good idea. Actually, my application has some iterations for finding the ROI. For HSV I use minH = 169; maxH = 7; minS = 0; maxS = 40; minV = 230; maxV = 30. Another iteration is based on LAB colors and 2 others based on Hasan Fleyeh's papers on segmentation. I examine these can be unsuccessfull in some cases (fog, sunset illumination) I also try to find other color signs including the white-black ones. I am searching if I could solve all colors with TanTriggs preprocessing in only one iterarion; and increase the performance.